# 'undefined method' when converting attribute in Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Pretty new to working with Modules. I can't get my Module method to convert a user inputed string ("1:48.55") to a float before I validate it and save it to the db. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules/)
```

**lib/modules/sport_time.rb**

```
module SportTime
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  attr_accessor :goal_time

  included do
    before_validation :sporty_save
  end

  def self.stringify_race(secs)
    m = (secs/60).floor
    s = (secs - (m*60))
    sprintf("%02d:%.2f\n",m,s)
  end

  private
  def sporty_save
    self.goal_time = self.goal_time.floatify_race(goal_time)  ---(line 12)---
  end

  def floatify_race(str)
    dirty = str.split(":")
    min = dirty[0]
    sec = dirty[1]
    seconds = (min.to_i * 60) + sec.to_f
    seconds.round(4)
  end
end
```

**app/models/event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SportTime
  validates_presence_of :event_type, :race_length, :course, :goal_time, :user_id
  attr_accessible :event_type, :race_length, :course, :goal_time, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**db/seed.rb**

```
Event.create(
  :event_type => 'Run',
  :race_length => 800,
  :course => 'outdoor',
  :goal_time => '01:48.55',
  :user_id => user_one.id
)
```

**ERROR:**

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `floatify_race' for "01:48.55":String
/Users/myname/work/projectname/lib/modules/sport_time.rb:12:in `sporty_save'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here.  You are calling `floatify_race` on a string but the string class does not have such a method because `floatify_race` is only defined for the class which you are extending.  There are a couple of ways you could fix this but one way would be to just pass the `goal_time` string as an argument to `floatify_race` like this:

`self.goal_time = floatify_race(self.goal_time)`

More importantly, if the datatype of `goal_time` is ultimately a float in the database, it's a little weird to first set it to a string and then convert it before saving.  I don't know the particulars of your app but maybe you want to convert the string to a float at the controller level after the user inputs a string.